# Can't reset title bar right-click behavior in Unity, Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: unity, 12.10, gconf

I recently upgraded from Ubuntu 12.04 to 12.10.

In 12.04, a title bar right-click would cause the menu to popup.  After my upgrade right-click shades/unshades the window.  I want the previous behavior, so I opened /apps/metacity/general in gconf settings, and saw that 'action_right_click_title_bar' was set to toggle-shade.  I switched the value to 'menu', logged out, then logged back in.  However, the behavior did not change.  I verified that 'action_right_click_title_bar' was still 'menu' (it was).   I also tried unsetting the key with no results.

How do I change the behavior to show the menu when the window title-bar is right-clicked?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know about 12.10, but maybe it's the same as 13.04 ? In 13.04, the schema is :

```
 org/gnome/desktop/wm/preferences : action-right-click-titlebar
```

- You can check the value with:

  ```
  gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences action-right-click-titlebar
  ```
- If it's not 'menu', you can set it with:

  ```
  gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences action-right-click-titlebar menu
  ```

Comment: Also working for Gnome 3.14 in Debian 8.0 Jessie (testing)